# NSLog on .mm file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, objective-c++

How do I print out something to the debugger console if the file is of .mm extension?

I tried `NSLog` and `printf` but none shows anything on the debugger console.

Answer (score 3):

NSLog works just fine in .mm files, as well as printf. Even `std::cout << "foo";` works great in .mm files because the extension marks the files as Objective-C++ file so you can mix C, C++ and ObjC in there.

If it doesn't print anything out, make sure that the program really reaches the point where you set the `NSLog`, you can place a few break points for this and then single step through your program.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with the type of the compilation unit (".mm" for Objective-C++ or ".m" for pure Objective-C). `NSLog` as well as `printf` work in both languages.

Your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing <Foundation/Foundation.h>

Add this line in the top of your class, this might help.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```